# How to use combineLatest with function that return dynamically Observable?

Tags: rxjs

If you use a function that returns different observable like:

```
const load = () => {
  if (!activated) {
    return of(null);
  } else {
    return of(123);
  }
}
```

And if you use `combineLatest`, it will always the the returned value at that moment, even if you change the `activated` to true.

```
combineLatest(load(), b)
  .pipe(map(([num, str]) => `${num}:${str}`))
  .subscribe(data => log(`result: ${data}`))


b.next('a');

activated = true; 

b.next('b'); // should log "123:b", but it doesn't
```

You can check the full example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/combinelatest-dynamically

Any solution to always get the updated version?

ps: I cannot have a single Subscription, cause it's a middleware from localStorage

Comment: Did my answer work for your intention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make `activated` observable and have it feed `load()`. The following is modified from your stackblitz.

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import {merge} from "rxjs/observable/merge";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { defer } from 'rxjs/observable/defer';

import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const activated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
const b = new ReplaySubject<any>();

const load = (activated) => {
  if (!activated) {
    return of(null);
  } else {
    return of(123);
  }
}

combineLatest(defer(() => activated.pipe(switchMap(x => load(x)))), b)
  .pipe(map(([num, str]) => `${num}:${str}`))
  .subscribe(data => log(`result: ${data}`))


b.next('a');

activated.next(true); 

b.next('b'); // should log "123:b", but it doesn't


// Utils
function log(v) {
    document.body.querySelector('pre').appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = v;
}
```

Comment: That's correct, also demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/combinelatest-dynamically-wssex3